# preventing keyboard drops while loading in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

In my iOS app, I need to focus on some text field, based on user's previous interactions. I could do the focusing using the javascript well, as follows (in the `viewDidFinshLoad` method)

```
if (![focusElement isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // make the keyboard freely appear without user intervention
    [webView setKeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction:NO];
    // first lose any previous focus and then focus on
    // the previously clicked element
    NSString *jsToFocus = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"document.activeElement.blur();document.getElementById(\'%s\').focus();",
                           [focusElement UTF8String]];

    // javascript focuses on the input
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsToFocus];
```

This works well. The only problem is when the page loads further frames/javascripts, the key board drops down and reappears a couple of times with every new load. I guess this is happening due to the earlier

```
   [webView setKeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction:NO];
```

Is there a (better) way to do this and more importantly, keep the keyboard displayed once focused on the input element, until the user dismisses it.

Thanks in advance.
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around to my problem, I introduced a property to the web view, called it

```
    @property BOOL isKeyBoardShown;
```

By default it is set to NO and as long as keyboad is not shown I allow loading further frames/elements. However, once I focus on the desired element I immediately set it to YES and forcibly stop any further loading. In short my `viewShouldStartLoad...` method looks like

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *)request
                                                 navigationType:  (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (self.isKeyBoardShown)
         return NO;

 ... further code ...
```

Then I introduced keyboard notifications

```
// set up keyboard notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object: nil];
```

And the method

```
- (void) keyboardWillBeHidden : (NSNotification *) keyboardHideNotice {
        self.isKeyBoardShown = NO;
}
```

So, the overall idea is focus on element -> show keyboard -> stop further loading as long as keyboard is up -> reset loading permissions on keyboard dismissal

This works fine, but now I have further problem:

If a user finishes inputing text and presses `search` or `go` key on the keyboard, because keyboard is still up and `isKeyboardShown` property is `YES`, webView does not proceed with the search unless user taps on the lens (dismissing the keyboard).

Is there a way I could detect the search key-press event? Note, the input is not a `UISearchBar`: (